# Is it possible to log out of Chrome using the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome

Google's Chrome browser (and Chromium) stores the saved passwords in a encrypted sqlite database where it is pretty safe. However, if the user is logged into Chrome, it is merely a matter of a few mouse clicks to reveal the passwords.

Because of that I would like to make a script that will automatically log me out of Chrome based on certain criteria, such as when my Linux PC is connected to a foreign network (which would be the case if it were stolen).

The script itself is not my main problem. What I don't know, however, is how to force Chrome to log me out using the command line.

Is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like you want to avoid losing all your passwords if your computer ever gets stolen. Logging out of Chrome isn't the answer to this.

Comment: It is part of the answer. There are more safety precautions such as a encrypted home folder.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider other more general security measures to protect the data of a running or suspended system:

- (automatically) lock your sessions when away from keyboard,
- encrypt your home directory or partition,
- encrypt the suspend image (dm-crypt, uswsusp, or tuxonice will do the job),
- encrypt the swap partition (dm-crypt), and
- use one or multiple strong pass phrases or even a smartcard in all of the above instances.

At this point it doesn't matter much, if the browser still has the master key in memory.

#### Rationale

If someone steals your notebook, he would have to guess your key, break the encryption, or analyse the memory content in case of a live system. The latter two are considered very difficult to achieve, whereas the difficulty of the first depends on the complexity of your key.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting this because I couldn't find the answer...
The trick is all about https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=en which logs you out.

For Conf room machines that may be left logged in and are set to always be running.

Create a bash file called `LogOutOfChome.sh` in `~/` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

pkill -a -i "Google Chrome"
sleep 3
Open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=en'
sleep 15
pkill -a -i "Google Chrome"
```

This kills all open instances of Chrome, waits 3 seconds, opens the Gmail logout URL, waits 15 seconds, then kills all instances of Chrome again.

From the terminal:
`chmod +x LogOutOfChrome.sh`,
which will make it executable.

Test it (note, this will close all your Chrome windows and log you out…..)
`./LogOutOfChrome.sh`

Use crontab to schedule it.
`crontab -l`     (this is a lower case `L`)
to list if you have anything else scheduled.
Edit your crontab with VI.
`crontab -e`
Type <kbd>i</kbd> (lower case `I`) to insert
Copy/Paste:

```
*   1   *   *   *   ~/LogOutOfChrome.sh
```

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, enter <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
to Write and Quit. 
This will run the script at (minute, hour, day month, day of week) at hour 1
(i.e., 1 AM) of each day.

To test this, if it was currently 2:15pm set it to:

```
17  14  *   *   *   ~LogOutOfChrome.sh
```

which is 17 minutes past 14:00 hours (i.e., 2:17 PM).

Answer (score 1):

use an external password program that can be set up with requiring a passcode generated by an app on your smartphone, or that can send a text with a one time password to access their database. My personal preference is LastPass.

`pkill` can be used to kill off processes - if you set up chrome to not remember your login details when starting a new session, this would be sufficient (settings > content settings > manage exceptions > add pattern: google.com > dropdown: clear on exit)